# syntax error in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `CANCEL_ORDER`(IN order_id INT, IN buyer_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT customer_user_id INTO @userid FROM orders WHERE id=order_id;
    IF @userid=buyer_user_id THEN
        UPDATE orders SET status='failed',canceled_at=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) WHERE id=order_id;
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Customer ID in orders does not match with given buyer_user_id', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1003;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ' SET autocommit=0;
>       START TRANSACTION;
>       SELECT customer_user_id INTO ' at line 3

hi frds, 
how to rectify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DELIMITER ;;" is not valid

use: `DELIMITER New_delimiter  Old_Delimiter_To_Finish_Line`

Both delimiters must be differents

In the code of the procedure use the old delimiter but finish it with the new code;
Restore the old delimiter

```
DELIMITER $;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `CANCEL_ORDER`(IN order_id INT, IN buyer_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT customer_user_id INTO @userid FROM orders WHERE id=order_id;
    IF @userid=buyer_user_id THEN
        UPDATE orders SET status='failed',canceled_at=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) WHERE id=order_id;
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Customer ID in orders does not match with given buyer_user_id', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1003;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END;$
DELIMITER ; $
```

The operation is as follows: The tokenisateur will extract the first query using the current delimiter `;`
The delimiter becomes `$`
The tokenisateur will extract the second query using the current delimiter `$` and ignore the old delimiter `;` Hence the different lines of the stored procedure will not be separated.

Then tokenisateur will extract the third request using Still active delimiter `$` delimiter and becomes;
This implies that to complete the last command must be one `;`

Other things:

- `START TRANSACTION;` changes automatically `autocommit`
- `@userid` is
  not defined
- `canceled_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ())` : Totally useless if the field is a TIMESTAMP. TIMESTAMP fields are automatically updated.

Comment: hello sir thanks for the help it wrked but i am having same problem with another procedure http://pastebin.com/Na4PfMgh  pleaseee help me out with this one

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the following method:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cancel_order`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `cancel_order`(IN order_id INT, IN buyer_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_cancel BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT TRUE INTO v_cancel FROM orders WHERE id=order_id AND customer_user_id=buyer_user_id;
    IF v_cancel THEN
    UPDATE orders SET STATUS='failed',canceled_at=NOW() WHERE id=order_id;
    COMMIT;
    ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Customer ID in orders does not match with given buyer_user_id', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1003;
    ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```